# Reduce the size of an icon during the animation

Tags: css, sass

I'm trying to reduce the size of the icon-container (from 110px in 0% to 50px in 100%) when the animation "slide-bck-top" is on focus. I tried to pass &__icon-container {} inside @keyframes but it didnt work.
here is my scss file:

```
.button {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  border: none;
  height: 150px;
  width: 230px;
  background-color: transparent;
  outline: none;

  &__icon-container {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    color: color(white-0);
    background-color: color(blue-150);
    box-shadow: 0px 4px 4px color(black-0, 0.25);
    padding: 20px;
    cursor: pointer;
  }

  &__icon {
    fill: currentColor;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
  }


  &:focus {
      animation: slide-bck-top 0.3s 1.5s cubic-bezier(0.47, 0, 0.745, 0.715) forwards;
  }

  @keyframes slide-bck-top {
    0% {
      transform: translateZ(0) translateY(0);
    }
    100% {
      transform: translateZ(-400px) translateY(-200px);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: It looks like you're missing `animation:` as a property in your `&:focus` - `animation: slide-bck-top 0.3s 1.5s cubic-bezier(0.47, 0, 0.745, 0.715) forwards;`

Comment: Oh yeah, I have chained animations so removed the one that has nothing to do with this, and took the animation with it :p so yeah, the animation is included

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is `@keyframes` won't allow you to pass a selector, since it's meant for properties and SCSS won't compile it correctly nested. It would be like passing the selector in the `color:` attribute.

What you could do is pass the `.button__icon-container` into the `:focus` and move the `@keyframes` outside of the `.button`, since `@keyframes` is really a global scope item and SCSS/SASS will still render it outside of the `.button` anyway.

```
.button {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  border: none;
  height: 150px;
  width: 230px;
  background-color: transparent;
  outline: none;

  &__icon-container {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    color: color(white-0);
    background-color: color(blue-150);
    box-shadow: 0px 4px 4px color(black-0, 0.25);
    padding: 20px;
    cursor: pointer;
  }

  &__icon {
    fill: currentColor;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
  }


  &:focus {
      animation: slide-bck-top 0.3s 1.5s cubic-bezier(0.47, 0, 0.745, 0.715) forwards;

      .button__icon-container {
         animation: make-small 0.3s 1.5s cubic-bezier(0.47, 0, 0.745, 0.715) forwards;
    }
  }
}


@keyframes slide-bck-top {
    0% {
      transform: translateZ(0) translateY(0);
    }
    100% {
      transform: translateZ(-400px) translateY(-200px);
    }
  }

  @keyframes make-small {
    0% {
      width: 110px;
      height: 110px;
    }
    100% {
      width: 50px;
      height: 50px;
    }
  }
```

It compiles to this:

```
.button {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  border: none;
  height: 150px;
  width: 230px;
  background-color: transparent;
  outline: none;
}
.button__icon-container {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  color: color(white-0);
  background-color: color(blue-150);
  box-shadow: 0px 4px 4px color(black-0, 0.25);
  padding: 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.button__icon {
  fill: currentColor;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
}
.button:focus {
  animation: slide-bck-top 0.3s 1.5s cubic-bezier(0.47, 0, 0.745, 0.715) forwards;
}
.button:focus .button__icon-container {
  animation: make-small 0.3s 1.5s cubic-bezier(0.47, 0, 0.745, 0.715) forwards;
}

@keyframes slide-bck-top {
  0% {
    transform: translateZ(0) translateY(0);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateZ(-400px) translateY(-200px);
  }
}
@keyframes make-small {
  0% {
    width: 110px;
    height: 110px;
  }
  100% {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try using the max-height property.

```
  @keyframes slide-bck-top {
    0% {
      transform: translateZ(0) translateY(0);
      max-height:110px;
    }
    100% {
      transform: translateZ(-400px) translateY(-200px);
      max-height:50px
    }
  }
```